# Div not positioning as it should - CSS problem

Tags: css, layout, xhtml, positioning

I'm working on a joomla site and customizing the template for the client.
First of all let me say this, I suck at getting things to be "beautiful" but I try, test and research a lot, I have not found the reason for this not working.

Ok let me explain:
I have this HTML that loads the menu and then puts an empty div (for clearfix) and then opens another div for the next element.

> (I'm having issues with the code parser on Stack overflow So I'm posting the code to pastie and linking from here.)

Ok so I have this [html](http://pastie.org/1483772) and this [css](http://pastie.org/1483779)

now as I see it, normally, the wrapper_menu should have at least 130px height (min-height property) and grow if needed. then the .clr clears the float, and the next element , since its a div should be put under it. So AFTER the menu_wrapper content.
It does not, the menu_wrapper is always 130px height, and when it grows, the whitebox element gets on top of it ( although the text is still visible, but not clickable).
I tried putting overflow auto on the wrapper and still it gets on top but the text is no longer seen.
you can see the test site [here](http://centre-dotcom.org/)

I really don't know what else to try in order to get this menu's div to grow with the content.

thanks

Cromestant.

Comment: Maybe go and accept some answers on your previous questions - otherwise maybe I'll get a coffee instead of investigating.

Comment: I just figured out that I had to, will go back and do it

Comment: feel kind like an idiot, had not seen the checkmark, I thought it was a badg I had to earn in order to mark as answered. Now I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `position: absolute;` on `ul.menu` which is taking out the ul from the document flow. Remove it and it will look much better.